# Custom Taglib error in Websphere -Error failed to locate setter method for attribute collection in tag class

Tags: jsp, migration, websphere, taglib

In our project we  have a taglib like below that works entirely fine in weblogic. Currently we are migrating to webshere where we are facing the exception

```
Error failed to locate setter method for attribute collection in tag class
```

The tag file is below:

```
<tag>
    <name>list</name>
    <tagclass>com.abc.jsp.taglib.list.ListTag</tagclass>
    <bodycontent>JSP</bodycontent>
    <info>
      A tag that implements a list
    </info>

    <!-- no default -->
    <attribute>
      <name>collection</name>
      <required>true</required>
      <rtexprvalue>false</rtexprvalue>
    </attribute>
    //more attributes go here 
  </tag>
```

the corresponding java class has getters and setters like this

```
/**
     * gets the items to iterate
     */
    public Object[] getCollection() {
        return collection;
    } 
/**
     * sets the collection to iterate over
     */
    public void setCollection(String collectionName) {
        Collection colxn = (Collection) pageContext.getRequest().getAttribute(
                collectionName);

        if (colxn != null) {
            collection = colxn.toArray();
        }
    }
```

some solution on the net was to upgrade SDK1.6 to SR6 in the below url

https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-10741

Can anyone please help us with this. Is there a workaround for this issue?

Comment: You have `Object[] getCollection()` method, but not corresponding setter, like `setCollection(Object[] param)`. Your tag has to follow javabean specification, so you either have to use `Object[]` or `String` in both getter and setter.

Comment: Yes @Gas I knew it that code has been working like this in weblogic but webspher eit fails. Hmm was seeing if there is any workaround one obivous way is to change the entire code.